# What is the best way to find an RF FET device for a design?

Tags: mosfet, rf, analog, jfet, fet

I'm searching for a jfet or mosfet for a receiver front end, but there doesn't seem to be many options. Everything I find seems to be obsolete. The closest thing I've found to a component that matches my needs is the NTE455, the VDS is 20V and if what I read was right it has a bandwidth of 900Mhz. Is there a better way of searching for fet components, or components in general? I usually just use the parametric search on Digikey, but I find this is very limited. Also, is there a way to calculate the cutoff frequency of a jfet given its parameters? I noticed a lot of datasheets leave this off, whereas almost all RF bjts have the transition frequency clearly listed.

Maybe someone could clear this up as well, is there a way to interpret part numbers or is it completely random? Take the 2N3819 for example, of course the 2N is the series designation, but does the 3819 mean anything? Or were these just chosen serially as the component was first released?

Comment: Have you looked in Digikey's RF FETs section? You're not going to find them with the ordinary FETs.

Comment: If you have it's parameters, then yes you can calculate the jfet cutoff frequency. (Just google -- you will see plenty of .edu sites on the topic.) And if the datasheet leaves it off, then it's probably not a high speed jfet.

Comment: Discrete JFETs are harder to find, too. Almost becoming boutique? So far as I'm aware the part numbers aren't nicely coded. At least, I've no idea how to fabricate a part number from requirements. You could also consider any of a variety of JFET input amplifiers. I don't know your application, so I'll toss out a swiss army knife part called the [LMH6518](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6518.pdf?ts=1642045679295&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLMH6518) which even includes separate follower output designed to work with oscilliscope triggering.

Comment: *Take the 2N3819 for example, of course the 2N is the series designation, but does the 3819 mean anything?* No, "2N" historically meant "2 PN junctions". Like 1N4001 is a diode which has one PN junction. An NPN or PNP transistor has two so their type number starts with 2N. 3819 is usually just a number that the manufacturer choose.